# prove $H(x)=x^\top x$ is constant along solutions of the sytem if $A(x)^\top + A(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Could someone please help me to understand the following:

> Having the differential equation: $\dot{x} = A(x)x$ where $A(x)$ is a real -valued matrix of dimension $n\times n$
>
> How can I prove that the function $H(x)=x^\top x$ is constant along solutions of the sytem if $A(x)^\top + A(x)=0$
>
> And how to prove that the origin is a Lyapunov stable fixed point if $A(x)^\top + A(x) \prec 0$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, differentiate!
$$
\frac{d}{dt} H(x(t)) = \dot{x}^Tx + x^T\dot{x} = (A(x)x)^T x + x^TA(x)x
= x^T(A^T(x) + A(x))x = 0.
$$

Now for stability, observe that when $A^T(x) + A(x) \prec 0$, the right hand side of the above equation is negative, so $\frac{d}{dt}H(x(t)) < 0$.  Thus, the norm-squared $x^Tx$ of the solution will be decreasing as a function of time.

Hope that helps.